# potential difference across a bulb

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

I am doing some self studying over the summer for fun and I'm working from a book that does not provide answers. I came across the following question, and I will present my solution. I was hoping someone could either verify or correct it.

A 100-W household light bulb is plugged into a wall outlet using a 100 ft extension cord made with #18 copper wire which has a diameter of 1.01 mm. If the potential difference across the two terminals of the outlet is 120 V, what is the potential difference across the light bulb?

My solution: $I_{cord} = \frac{V_{cord}}{R_{cord}}$ Now, $R_{cord} = \frac{L}{\sigma_cA}$. From a table, I see $\sigma_c = 5.7 * 10^7 (\Omega m)^{-1}$. Plugging this data into my calculator, and computing A as $\pi r^2$ (The cross section is assumed to be circular in my book) I found, and you may check that $I_{cord} = 179.7933A$.

$V_{bulb} = \frac{Power_{bulb}}{I_{bulb}} = \frac{100W}{179.7933A} = 0.55619V$

Update: As pointed out, my solution is not correct.

I am wondering if there is a piece of information carelessly left out by the author: When one says that bulb is 100-W, does that mean it is 100-W at 120V, which would tell me the resistance of the bulb? Somehow I have to find the resistance of the bulb which is not given.

Comment: Hint:  do a sanity check.  Most household receptacle circuits (in the US) have a 15A (or perhaps 20A) circuit breaker and, as you know, connecting a 100W light bulb (more or less) directly to a duplex outlet does not cause the circuit breaker to trip.  Does it seem even remotely plausible that connecting a 100W light bulb with a 100ft extension cord will result in about 180A of current?

Comment: I felt like my solution was wrong. Am I correct that the bulb and the cord are in series?

Comment: The 100 ft extension cord is composed of two 100 ft conductors and these conductors and bulb are indeed series connected.  Thus, the fastest way to find the voltage across the bulb is to use voltage division.  You know the resistance of the 200 ft of conductor and the approximate resistance of the bulb is easily calculated.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri It's the resistance that I'm struggling to see how to compute.

Comment: @ Everybody, I don't understand why I was down voted. I sensibly phrased my question, and gave a very detailed (unfortunately wrong) answer to the question. Please, whoever down voted me, please explain so that I can improve next time I post a question. Thanks.

Comment: Unexplained downvotes are common here.  I would hazard a guess that the downvoter was annoyed by the "check my work" nature of the question.  See, for example, this meta post:  http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6159/9887

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When one says that bulb is 100-W, does that mean it is 100-W at 120V,
>   which would tell me the resistance of the bulb? Somehow I have to find
>   the resistance of the bulb which is not given.

Recall that, for a resistor, the AC power dissipated is

$$P_R = \frac{v_{rms}^2}{R}$$

*Assuming the voltage across the bulb is not significantly reduced by the extension cord,* the resistance of the 100W, 120VAC bulb can be approximated by solving the above equation for $R$.

Update:  from a comment by the OP:

> I won't downvote you, but if you read a clever solution below, you
>   "DON'T" have to assume 120VAC,

Actually, your downvote would have been ironic and I would have appreciated it for that fact.

To see this, note that in the (clever) accepted solution below, it is assumed that the bulb receives 100W of power but this *isn't true unless there is 120VAC across the bulb*.

In other words, assuming the bulb receives 100W of power assumes the voltage across the bulb is 120VAC just as I do above.

Let's compare the results.  Using the formula above, the resistance of the bulb is approximately

$$R = \frac{(120V)^2}{100W} = 144 \Omega$$

[This is a *good* approximation if the voltage across the bulb is approximately 120VAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb#Current_and_resistance).

Assuming the series resistance of the 200 feet of conductor is $0.167\Omega$, the voltage across the bulb is, by voltage division,

$$V_{bulb} = 120\frac{144}{144+0.167} =  119.9\mathrm{VAC}$$

So, the approximation is *valid*. The power delivered the bulb is then

$$P_{bulb} = \frac{(119.9V)^2}{144 \Omega} = 99.8W$$

thus the approximation of 100W is (of course) also valid.

Do you still wish to not downvote?

Comment: I won't downvote you, but if you read a clever solution below, you "DON'T" have to assume 120VAC, which is really what I've been wondering. Indeed there is a way to figure it out without that assumption which the author did not give to me since we really don't need it. You can set up two equations with two unknowns. See the comments in the answer below.

Comment: @user7348, I'm quite aware of how to solve this problem exactly as well as how to solve it approximately as in the above.  Go ahead and downvote, it will only diminish you.  In fact, I insist that you downvote it.

Comment: not sure if you read my message, but I said, I "won't" downvote you. I understand that you found another way to approximate the solution, which is not what I wanted, but because I recognize it's correct in its own way, I won't downvote you.

Comment: @user7348, I understood your message but you didn't understand mine.  Please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add the resistors for the light bulb and cord in series.

$$I_{system} = \frac{120V}{R_{cord}+R_{bulb}}$$

**Edit:**

Your math seems to be correct on the resistance of the cord though.  I get 0.167 Ohm

Now, multiplying out by the current to get power, since the energy drop across the bulb is 100W:

$$I_{system}^2(0.167 Ohm) + 100W = 120V*I_{system}$$

The current would be the solution of the quadratic - *0.834 Amps*

Using this current, the resistance across the bulb is simple - **143.7 Ohms.**

Comment: how do you know they are in parallel?

Comment: they should be in series. plus your equation isn't correct.

Comment: They are in series, not parallel.  And, the answer given above is correct if $R_{coord}$ is the total resistance for each conductor which would be 200 feet in total.  The current flows through a closed loop that includes one conductor on one side of the extension cord, the filament, and then the other conductor on the other side of the extension cord.  Note that there is a voltage drop across the conductors as well as the filament.

Comment: It's impossible to compute that though because I don't know R_bulb.

Comment: The total voltage must add to the 120 volts supply.  This is the total of the voltage drops across each side of the extension cord plus the $R_{bulb}$.  So, you know everything except $R_{bulb}$.  You can solve for the resistance of the bulb from what you have but you don't need it.  You have all the other voltages:  $$V_{bulb} = 120 - V_{cord}$$ and assuming that $V_{coord}$ is the total voltage drop across both sides of the extension cord.

Comment: @K7PEH I still have to compute V_coord. To do so, I need to some over the whole circuit the resistances, you know how it works.

Comment: @K7PEH See my update above. I believe the author assumed we know that a bulb with 100W is meant at 120V which is standard in the US. Agree?

Comment: You have two equations and two unknowns.  Now, the exact equations and unknowns depends on how you approach the problem.  But, here are two equations and two unknowns:$$I=\frac{120}{2 R_{coord} + R_{bulb}}$$ and $$R_{bulb} = \frac{100}{I^2}$$ and the unknowns are $I$ and $R_{bulb}$ since you can easily compute $R_{coord}$ which I am taking to be the resistance of just one conductor of the two conductor extension cord.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25088/discussion-between-user7348-and-k7peh).

Comment: Sorry, I have a ham radio CW net that I am late for now.

Comment: Your .167 ohms is incorrect, so I unchecked you as the best answer.